# Using Generics for attribute of Java Class

Tags: java, generics

I have a requirement where the Type of attribute of a class is generic and will be decided runtime. Hence I came up with below class definition

```
public class Generics<T> {

    T t1;

    public void put(T t2){
        t1 = t2;
    }

}
```

Before creating an object, I know the type. Hence I wonder how to instantiate. I tried the following, but it gives compilation error. What exactly is the right way ?

```
Object obj = getObjFromFactory() // obj can be type say A.class or B.class. I wish to get the class of obj and pass it to Generics

Generics<obj.class> generics = new Generics<obj.class>();
```

Comment: Note that `Generics generics` would create a _raw_ type which means any generics checks would be deactivated. Also it would be `new Generics<Sample>()` since the type is a class anyways so there's no need to use `Sample.class`.

Comment: I think we have an XY problem here. You can't decide the type of a generic class in Java in runtime. Java generics are compile-time constructs, and in runtime all generics are erased. Thus, you need to tell us the context, what attribute you are working with and what needs to be determined at runtime, and maybe we can help you choose something other than generics for it.

Comment: I updated my question, Please check. I have a base object from which i need to derive the class to pass to generics class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know the type until run-time you cannot name it explicitly but you can use a type-parameter to tie the type of different pieces of the code that you can be sure make reference to the same type whatever it is:

```
private <T> void myRutine(final Factory<T> factory) {
   // ...
   final T obj = factory.getObj();
   // ...
   final Generics<T> generics = new Generics<>();
   // ...
   generics.put(obj);
   // ...
}
```

In the code above you are delegating on the calling code to determine `T` it it can. If it cannot it might just use `?`:

```
Factory<?> f = codeToCreateFactory();
myRutine(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Generics<Sample> generics = new Generics<>();
```

See: [Oracle Java Tutorials - Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: Correct. You may want to add that prior to Java 7 it has to be `Generics<Sample> generics = new Generics<Sample>();` as the diamond operator was introduced in Java 7.

Comment: I updated my question, Can you please check. I have a base object from which i need to derive the class to pass to generics

Comment: Your `getObjFromFactory()` will need to be a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). Then you can do `Generics<Sample> generics = getObjFromFactory();` Note that there is never `.class` in the type parameter, so don't use `.class`. Also, this is not going to work if you don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: The question says that the type will be resolved at run-time. This solution requires the type ```Sample`` to be know a compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

You do that the same way as with collections

not like this:

```
List<Integer.class> myVarList = ...;
```

but

```
List<Integer> myVarList = ...;
```

so in your case

```
 Generics<Sample> generics = new Generics<>();
```

or for older java versions

```
 Generics<Sample> generics = new Generics<Sample>();
```

Comment: I updated my question, Can you please check. I have a base object from which i need to derive the class to pass to generics.